# Регулярное выражение с исключениями

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Приветствую всех вошедших

Уважаемые, прошу маленького отступления. В свое время, давным давно, подрабатывал на верстке HTML, задание примитивное но все же. Так вот была группа мъсье программистов, в основном с уклоном на JS, которым не жить не быть в место:

```
<table><tr><td></td><td></td></tr></table>
```

всегда использовали

```
<table><tr><td><td>
```

типа браузер сам додумает, и приходилось действовать так же. Ест-но такое можно только на практике проверить. Теория идет боком.

Относительно недавно начал разбираться в регулярных выражениях, но одну конструкцию не могу разобрать вообще, прошу хоть немного пояснить, как она будет работать

```
/^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3 }(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/
```

ну понятное дело [0-9], [0-5]. Но скажем |2[0-9] в место [0-9]{2}, круглые скобки внутри круглых, или ?:25 ... ту же запись {3,50} или {3,} - можно понять, а вот {3 }

Может ли кто объяснить, является ли это стандартным или нет, и уж позвольте обнаглеть и спросить, что это значит?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `|2[0-9] в место [0-9]{2}`

Это не вместо, а 2 совершенно разные конструкции. В первом случае "двойка, после которой идёт одна цифра от 0 до 9". Во втором - "группа из двух цифр от 0 до 9".

> круглые скобки внутри круглых

Точно такая же группировка, как и любая другая. Например, вот это:

```
print "$1, $2\n" if '123' =~ /(\d(\d)\d)/;
```

выведет:

```
123, 2
```

> или `?:25`

Не "**?:25**", нужно рассматривать конструкцию целиком: `(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]...)`, в общем случае `(?:шаблон)`. Это тоже группировка.

> уж позвольте обнаглеть и спросить, что это значит?

Позвольте тоже обнаглеть и предложить почитать какой-нибудь учебник или руководство по регекспам, что ли... Например, [хотя бы это](http://citforum.ru/internet/perl/regexp/) (первые пару абзацев можно пропустить, там про Perl, но остальное - оно самое).